# ModalPopupExtender textbox not populating with child gridview data

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

So I am using a Modal Popup for gridview editing. The gridview is a child gridview of another gridview. I have moved the modal popup out of the updatepanel due to issues of it adding commas to the beginning of the textbox on submitting it to database. The textbox was being populated prior to me moving the modal popup out of the update panel, however now since it is no longer in the update panel with the gridview, it does not populate the text boxes with the gridview data. Any one have any suggestions?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>

   <div style="background-color:white;text-align:center; padding:10px;border-radius:15px;box-shadow:5px 10px 15px #303A4C;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; max-width:100%;min-width:30%;float:left;">
   <h2 class="h2title">

    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" style="float:left;margin-left:10px;">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">--Select--</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Options</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Parts</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Bid Rates</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
     Purchasing Approval</h2>

     <asp:Panel ID="panel1" runat="server" Visible="false"  Width="100%">
     <div class="griddiv" style="overflow-y:scroll;max-height:500px; max-width:80%;">

     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" CellPadding="5" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        RowStyle-CssClass="rows" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridheader" DataKeyNames="batchID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" >

                            <Columns>
                               <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <img alt = "" style="cursor: pointer" src="../img/plus.png" />
                                    <asp:Panel ID="childpanel" runat="server" Style="display: none;">
                                    <div class="griddiv" style="overflow-y:scroll;max-height:500px; max-width:80%;">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="gvchild" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" CellPadding="5" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                                        CssClass="datagrid1" RowStyle-CssClass="rows" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridheader" DataKeyNames="id">
                                            <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px" HeaderText = "">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Text = "Edit" OnClick = "Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Option Number">  
                                                <ItemTemplate>  
                                                        <asp:Label ID="optionnumtemp" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("optionnum") %>'></asp:Label>  
                                                    </ItemTemplate>  
                                                </asp:TemplateField>  
                                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="id" HeaderText="ID" />
                                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="optionnum" HeaderText="Option Number" />
                                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="optiondesc" HeaderText="Option Description" />
                                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="optioncat" HeaderText="Option Category" />
                                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="houseplan" HeaderText="House Plan" />
                                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="craftcode" HeaderText="Craft Code" />
                                                <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="parentoption" HeaderText="Parent Option" />
                                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkHeader" TextAlign="Right"/>
                                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                                <asp:TemplateField>
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkRow"/>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                            </Columns>
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                        </div>

                                    </asp:Panel>

                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField = "batchID" HeaderText = "Batch ID" HtmlEncode = "true" HeaderStyle-Width="25%" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField = "requestdate" HeaderText = "Request Date" HtmlEncode = "true" HeaderStyle-Width="25%" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField = "requestby" HeaderText = "Requested By" HtmlEncode = "true" HeaderStyle-Width="25%"/>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField = "entityname" HeaderText = "Division" HtmlEncode = "true" HeaderStyle-Width="25%"/>

                            </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>
                         <div class="button">
                                             <asp:Button ID="Button" runat="server" Text="Complete" />
                                       </div>
                        </div>
                        </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "GridView1" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID = "btnSave" />
          </Triggers>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
         <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddEdit" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" style = "display:none">
                                <asp:Label Font-Bold = "true" ID = "Label4" runat = "server" Text = "Option Request" ></asp:Label>
                                <br />
                                <table align = "center">
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="rowid" runat="server" Text = "ID"></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label ID = "Label1" runat = "server" Text = "Option Number" ></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="optionnumtxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label ID = "Label2" runat = "server" Text = "Option Description" ></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="optiondesctxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>   
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label ID = "Label3" runat = "server" Text = "Option Category" ></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="optcattxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label ID = "Label5" runat = "server" Text = "House Plan" ></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="houseplantxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label ID = "Label6" runat = "server" Text = "Craft Code" ></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="craftcodetxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Label ID = "Label7" runat = "server" Text = "Parent Option" ></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="parentoptiontxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick = "Save" />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" OnClientClick = "return Hidepopup()"/>
                                </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>
                                </asp:Panel>
                               <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFake" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="popup" runat="server" DropShadow="false"
                                    PopupControlID="pnlAddEdit" TargetControlID = "lnkFake"
                                    BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
                                </ajax:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Protected Sub Edit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

```
For Each gvrow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
    Dim gvchild As GridView = TryCast(gvrow.FindControl("gvchild"), GridView)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = CType(CType(sender, LinkButton).Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)

    rowid.Text = row.Cells(1).Text
    optionnumtxt.Text = row.Cells(2).Text
    optiondesctxt.Text = row.Cells(3).Text
    optcattxt.Text = row.Cells(4).Text
    houseplantxt.Text = row.Cells(5).Text
    craftcodetxt.Text = row.Cells(6).Text
    parentoptiontxt.Text = row.Cells(7).Text
    popup.Show()

Next
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while with no response, I tried to figure out a hack to this that will work for my circumstance.

```
parentoption = parentoption.Split(",").Last()
```

this remove the commas and anything preceeding the commas so that the only text that is submitted is the new text that is entered.